# Windows Phone 8.1: USSD

Tags: sdk, windows-phone-8.1, ussd

Does Windows Phone 8.1 SDK support USSD? If yes, where is the documentation? I can't find anything related or any third-party APIs that Read/Write the USSD in the Windows Phone platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn391812.aspx) what you are looking for? It is only for Windows 8.0 and 8.1 - it appears that there is no information for the Windows Phone SDK...